# Como pegar dados específicos de retorno de um JSON com Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic2, ionic3

Acredito que seja simples, mas saindo do Ionic 1 para o 3, mudou tantas coisas.

Preciso pegar todos os retornos de meu Json desta rotina (na verdade preciso do ID do usuário e registrar em localstorage):

```
submit(){
      var email = this.data.email;
      var senha = this.data.senha;
    var link = 'http://localhost/webapi/consultarEmailSenha.php?email='+email+'&senha='+senha;
       //var myData = JSON.stringify({email: this.data.email}) + JSON.stringify({senha: this.data.senha});

       console.log(link);

       this.http.get(link)
       .subscribe(data => {
           this.data.response = data["_body"]; //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574305/property-body-does-not-exist-on-type-response
           console.log(this.data.response[0]);
           console.log(this.data.response[1]);
           console.log(this.data.response[2]);
           console.log(this.data.response[3]);
           console.log(this.data.response[3]);
       }, error => {
           console.log("Oooops!");
       });
```

O retorno do Json está assim:

```
[{"idusuarios":"1","nome":"Ramos J","email":"meu@mail.com","celular":null,"telefone":"","data_nascimento":"1978-07-19","altura":null,"peso":null,"gordura":null,"vo2":null,"senha":"teste"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma modificação para que vc veja como transformar o retorno em um objeto JSON e iterar cada item do array.

```
submit(){
  var email = this.data.email;
  var senha = this.data.senha;
  var link = 'http://localhost/webapi/consultarEmailSenha.php?email='+email+'&senha='+senha;

  this.http.get(link).subscribe(data => {
       var array = JSON.parse(data);
       json.forEach(element => {
           console.log(element.idusuarios);
       });
  }, error => {
       console.log("Oooops!");
  });
}
```

Comment: Deu certo @NilsonUehara. Só mudei um pouco:  var array = JSON.parse(this.data.response);
           array.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.idusuarios);
           });